# 24 bit display error message

Tags: virtualbox, display-settings

I installed VirtualBox on a Win 7 64bit OS.  When I create a Win 7 VM inside Virtual box it keeps telling me that I am configured for 24 bit display and need 32 bit.  But my base Win7 is set at 32 bit.  I don't know how to fix this - any suggestions>

Comment: Have you looked around in the VirtualBox settings? If the VM is saying that, it shouldn't be your host OS that is causing the problems... it should be a BIOS / other setting in your VM (that's my guess)